# How to create a row of identical images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image and I want to create a row of 5 copies of that image. The simplest way I see of doing that is the following:

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/penny.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/penny.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/penny.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/penny.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/penny.png'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

However, this approach is obviously incredibly repetitive. I could write a function for the Expanded widget to make it look a little cleaner, but is there a better approach that is less repetitive and will allow me to easily control how many duplicate images I can create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing it with GridView, so I think I'll use this, as it'll also be useful later when I want to create more pennies. (Like for 100 pennies, I would want to display them in several rows and not just one.)

```
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 5 ,
  children: List.generate(5,(index){
    return Container(
      child: Image.asset('images/penny.png'),
    );
  }),
)
```

To make this even more customizable:

```
GridView build2DArrayOfPennies(int rowCount, int numItems, String imageFile) {
return GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: rowCount,
  children: List.generate(numItems,(index){
    return Container(
      child: Image.asset(imageFile),
    );
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Container(
                     
                      child: Row(
                        children: List.generate(
                            5,
                            (index) => Expanded(
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/yourImage'))),
                      ))
```